# How to pass two functions in the same route in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, function, model, controller

i have this route:

web.php:

```
Route::get('main',[HomePageController::class,'show']);
```

that pass this function:

HomePageController.php

```
class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    function show()
    {
        $data = Classes::all();
        return view('index',['classes'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

and i want to pass another function in the same route but i keep getting "Undefined variable"
whenever i try to do this:

web.php

```
Route::get('main',[HomePageController::class,'show']);
Route::get('main',[HomePageController::class,'showfeeds']);
```

HomePageController.php

```
class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    function show()
    {
        $data = Classes::all();
        return view('index',['classes'=>$data]);
    }

    function showfeeds()
    {
        $data = Feeds::all();
        return view('index',['feeds'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use single route but send `Classes` and `Feeds` to single view (as you intended):

Route:

```
Route::get('main',[HomePageController::class,'show']);
```

Controller:

```
class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    function show()
    {
        $classes = Classes::all();
        $feeds = Feeds::all();
        return view('index', compact('classes', 'feeds'));
    }
}
```